# Java, is delegating the logging to a different class a bad practice?

Tags: java, oop, logging, log4j, slf4j

In Java logging, it is typical to acquire the logger instance per class as such

```
public class Foo {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

    public void doSomething() {
        logger.info("doSomething called");
    }
}
```

But is it a bad practice to delegate the logging from multiple classes to a single logging service, for example

```
@Stateless
public class LoggingService {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerService.class);

    public void info(String context, String messsage) {
        logger.info(context + message);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class Foo {

    @EJB
    LoggingService logger;

    public void doSomething() {
        logger.info("Foo", "doSomething called");
    }
}

@Stateless
public class Bar {

    @EJB
    LoggingService logger;

    public void doSomething() {
        logger.info("Bar", "doSomething called");
    }
}
```

Is this acceptable, or is there some practical reason the logger per class approach is favored?

Comment: You would lose the ability to filter the log messages by logger (i.e. by class), while making your code more complex than with the classical way of doing (forcing you to pass a context to every method call, impossible to filter). What would be the point?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this acceptable, or is there some practical reason the logger per
>   class approach is favored?

1) It is not a good practice because you may want to configure the logging to log at some levels some packages and other levels for other packages.
If all logs are written from the same class you cannot do that as all your applicative logs will be writen from the same exact package.

2) The used approach produces a reading indirection. So your pears have to dig into the `LoggingService` to know how the logging operations are actually done.

3) Logging APIs provide multiple ways to log.
To be compliant with standard logging (such as SLF4J), you should so provide the same exact methods in your `LoggingService` class and you should also update your class according to the standard in terms of logging. It represents an important duty that you want to spare for yourself.